# Allowing arbitrary files to be matched by find

Tags: bash, find

I am passing arguments to bash function, composed of directories and files.  The following code validates the arguments before staring then in the array `fdir`.

```
declare -A tag
for arg in "$@"; do
  printf '%s\n' "arg: $arg"  
  [[ -d "$arg" || -f "$arg" ]] || continue
  [[ ${tag[$arg]} ]] && continue
  fdir+=("$arg")
  tag[$arg]=1
done
```

Finally, I pass the contents of `fdir` to the find `command` and finally run `head` on the matched files.

```
local _GREP="/bin/grep --color"
hn=13
sufx=( \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.c' \) )
mxdpt=( -maxdepth 3 )
find "${fdir[@]}" -type f "${sufx[@]}" "${mxdpt[@]}"  \
  -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' +
```

Because I use `sufx` in the file command, if I pass a different type of file (e.g. `/home/flora/file.org`), the `find` will not find a match.

One solution would be to have directories to precede files in the array `fdir`. Loop through each element in `fdir` and set `sufx=()` as soon as I detect the first file.

```
   declare -A tag

   local daggr=()
   for arg in "$@"; do
     [[ ! -d "$arg" ]] || continue
     [[ ${tag[$arg]} ]] && continue
     daggr+=("$arg")
     tag[$arg]=1
   done

   local faggr=()
   for arg in "$@"; do
     [[ ! -f "$arg" ]] && continue
     [[ ${tag[$arg]} ]] && continue
     faggr+=("$arg")
     tag[$arg]=1
   done

   fdir=( "${daggr[@]}" "${faggr[@]}" )

 for (( i=0 ; i < $n ; i++ )); do
   [[ -f "${fdir[$i]}" ]] && { sufx=() ; mxdpt=() ; }
   find "${fdir[$i]}" -type f "${sufx[@]}" "${mxdpt[@]}"  \
     -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' +
 done
```

Any advice on better or simpler ways that I could try?

Comment: "arbitrary files, but allow matches using sufx for directories" makes in my understanding sense only if you have directories with names `*.sh` and `*.c`. Please give an example tree structure. `find` shall descend only into (sub)directories with these suffixes?

Comment: `*.sh` and `*.c` are the file extensions. I want to be able to do `myfunc /home/flora/lin /home/flora/mol/edv.f`.

Comment: One solution would be to have directories to precede files in the array `fdir`.  Loop through each element in `fdir` and set `sufx=()` as soon as I detect the first file.

Comment: I suspect you need to run two different `find` commands, one for directories and one for files. BTW, what versions of bash allow `sufx=( ( -name *.sh -o -name *.c ) )` without quotes/escapes?

Comment: Have included the quotes and escapes.  I want to avoid repeating the command.

Comment: Sounds like you want either use the `-H` option of `find` or change the `[[ -f/-d file ]]` to `[[ -f/-d file && ! -L file ]]`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to quote this:

```
sufx=( \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.c' \) )
```

If `find` shall apply `-exec` to all files in `"${fdir[@]}"` but only to certain files within the passed directories then a simple approach would be to have two `find` calls:

```
find "${fdir[@]}" -maxdepth 0 -type f -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' +
find "${fdir[@]}" -mindepth 1 -type f "${sufx[@]}" "${mxdpt[@]}"  \
  -exec head -v -n "$hn" '{}' +
```

Comment: I want to avoid a repeat.

Comment: @Aardvark, the alternative would be to add some `-path filepath_escaped` *or*ed together for each of the regular files (with wildcard characters escaped) which IMO would not be worth the effort.

Comment: Is it acceptable to pass a filename rather than a directory to the find command?  E.g. `find /home/flora/linear.rc -print`

Comment: @Aardvark, yes, of course, can be a file of any type whether it's *regular*, *fifo*, *directory*, *symlink*, etc. However note that unless you pass some `-H`/`-L` option (or use the `-follow` predicate), files of type *symlinks* will be considered as symlinks not as whatever type the file they eventually resolve to it. For symlinks to directories for instance, that means the corresponding directory will not be walked down. Compare with `[`'s `-d` or `-f` which tests the type of the file *after* symlink resolution (respectively for dir or regular, excluding all other types of files).

Comment: Will the command `find -H "${fdir[@]}" -type f \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.c' \)` always work when passing files and directories in `fdir`?